# How to update object without deleting the data are saved before laravel mongo

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent

i have the data:

```
 {
"_id": {
  "$oid": "5e8f2c11b23e476f93551e13"
},
"vehicle_component_id": 3,
"damages_types": [
  1,
  7
],
"mileages": [
  "0"
],
"damages": {
  "1": {
    "upper_bound": [
      null
    ],
    "damages": [
      "0"
    ],
    "lower_bound": [
      null
    ]
  },
  "7": {
    "upper_bound": [
      null
    ],
    "damages": [
      "0"
    ],
    "lower_bound": [
      null
    ]
  }
},
"created_at": "2020-04-09 16:07:13",
"updated_at": "2020-04-09 16:07:13"
```

}

and i need to add a new object to damages object and keep all the other data in damages, i'm trying to do it like

```
    DB::connection($this->mongoCon)
        ->collection($this->table)
        ->where(['vehicle_component_id' => (int) $vehicleComponentId])
        ->update(
            [
                "damages" => [
                    6 => ["upper_bound" => null], ["damages" => 2], ["lower_bound" => null],
                ],
            ]);
```

but the result is

```
"damages": {
  "6": {
    "upper_bound": [
      null
    ],
    "damages": [
      "2"
    ],
    "lower_bound": [
      null
    ]
  }
}
```

and i'm trying to make it like

```
"damages": {
      "1": {
        "upper_bound": [
          null
        ],
        "damages": [
          "0"
        ],
        "lower_bound": [
          null
        ]
      },
     "6": {
        "upper_bound": [
          null
        ],
        "damages": [
          "2"
        ],
        "lower_bound": [
          null
        ]
      }
      "7": {
        "upper_bound": [
          null
        ],
        "damages": [
          "0"
        ],
        "lower_bound": [
          null
        ]
      }
    }
```

so the question will be how to add the new data to the damages object without deleting the old data thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

To set a field in embedded documents you could directly use the [`dot notation`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents) with the `$set` operator. (Rather than using `$set` to define the whole `damages` document)

The following query is likely what you are looking for:

```
db.collection.update(
  { vehicle_component_id: vehicleComponentId },
  {
    $set: {
      "damages.6": { upper_bound: [null], damages: ["2"], lower_bound: [null] },
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: yup this what i did after i posted the question :), i will add my laravel solution later but basically its the same as yours

Answer (score 0):

this is my first time using the mongo with laravel so i'm new with that and my solution is as normal mongo query as mentioned before in the Answer of @ambianBeing

```
        DB::connection($this->mongoCon)
        ->collection($this->table)
        ->where(['vehicle_component_id' => (int) $vehicleComponentId])
        ->update(
            [
                "damages.6" =>
                    ["upper_bound" => null], ["damages" => 2], ["lower_bound" => null],
            ]);
```

maybe another advice use this method "dot notation" to add data on objects and push  to add data to arrays.